# Why isn't there a warning for null == null?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse displays a warning when comparing two identical expressions :

```
if (1 == 1) -> warning
if (a == a) -> warning
```

However, no warning is shown for `null == null` (despite the fact that `null == null` is always true) :

```
if (null == null) -> no warning
```

Is there any reason for this ?

Comment: null will always be null, but as `null` identifies an object (that doesn't exists, but still, an object), it still has to be compared.

Comment: @Laurens but then, why a warning for a==a ? (a being a null object)

Comment: Because YOU initialized `a`. You did not tell the compiler what `null` was

Comment: Isn't it because `a` and `1` have a state and `null` is the absence of state ?

Comment: Are you looking for an authoritative answer from someone who is intimately familiar with that code?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I'm trying to understand the logic leading to this fact. I guess it has something to do with what null is in java, but I'm failing to see it (but Laurens comment is a good hint, I think)

Comment: @Laurens but then, does it mean that `null` is not known by the compiler (as a keyword) ?

Comment: @fxm to some degree. It's a constant, but that constant is referring to a memory block that does not exist.

Comment: @Laurens so this also explains why  `"a" == "a"` does not raise any warning either ?

Comment: One difference is that "1: and "a" are instances of some type whereas null is not an instance of anything.  It's not an instance of nothing either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to think about what this warning condition is trying to prevent. Its purpose is to warn you that you are not comparing the two variables you intended to compare, such as due to a typo (eg `foo == foo` when you meant `foo == boo` or `foo == fpp`), or two literal values (eg `1 == 1`).

(Of course, comparing two literal values presents a different problem - the result will always be the same, and should just be simplified to `true` or `false` in the code anyway.)

`null == null` isn't a case of this potential problem. If you're naming a variable something close to "null" and then writing "null" by mistake, you've got an entirely different problem that no compiler can guess at.

Answer (score 1):

For *primitive* types like **int** and **char**, the value is known to the compiler. You can compare them and it is immediately picked up as identical values causing a warning.

For example:

```
'A' == 'A'
```

Or even:

```
'A' == 97
```

For *objects*, the value is not yet known to the compiler. It has not been allocated a space in memory where this value sits. The reference to the value needs to be checked at run-time even if it is the Null Reference.

For example:

```
null == null
```

or

```
"abc" == "abc"
```

However, you will get a warning for comparing an object to itself. This is because you have defined this object explicitly so the compiler knows it is identical without having to check its value.